# Error TS 2732 when trying to add JSON to Typescript

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I am trying to import a JSON file into a typescript program, and keep receiving error TS2732: Cant find module. the file with the JSON file i am trying to import is in the src folder along with the main.ts file. my code is as follows

import logs = require('./logs/logs_0.json')

console.log(logs.id)

Comment: Do you have 
    "resolveJsonModule": true
in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: yes, i have it turned on

Answer (score 4):

1. Not sure what version of typescript you're running but there was a bug introduced in version 2.9.0 that was fixed with 2.9.2
2. In your tsconfig.json, under the compiler options make sure to have:

   "resolveJsonModule": true,

   "esModuleInterop": true,

The esModuleInterop is only necessary for the default import of the json file. If you leave it set to false then you have to import it with import * as logs0 from '../logs_0.json'

Comment: I have both of these, still experiencing the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `resolveJsonModule` set to true in tsconfig.json as @Daniel M suggested, you can try something like this:

```js
import logs from './logs/logs_0.json';

console.log(logs.id);
```

`require` is something you would usually use in a javascript file.

Also make sure that on the same level with the file that has this import, you have `logs` folder, which contains your json. If json file is on the same level as typescript file, you might want to try importing from `./logs_0.json`.